# Simple app getting "undefined reference to vtable" error? [Qt]

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to make the code found on [this page](http://www.codeprogress.com/cpp/libraries/qt/showQtExample.php?index=145&key=QMainWindowPartialTransparent) compile. All I want to do is replicate what that page describes. I keep getting an error that says:

```
main.cpp:13: error: undefined reference to `vtable for myMainWindow'
```

Here's my code, which is pretty much exactly like the code on that page:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QBitmap>

class myMainWindow : public QMainWindow
{

public:
myMainWindow():QMainWindow()
  {
    setMask((new QPixmap("saturn.png"))->mask());
      QPalette* palette = new QPalette();
      palette->setBrush(QPalette::Background,QBrush(QPixmap("saturn.png")));
      setPalette(*palette);

      setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
      QWidget *centralWidget = new QWidget(this);
      QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout();

      centralWidget->setLayout(layout);

      QPushButton* button1 = new QPushButton("Button 1");
      button1->setFixedSize(80,50);

      layout->addWidget(button1,0,0);

      setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
  };
  ~myMainWindow();
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  myMainWindow *window = new myMainWindow();

    window->resize(600, 316);
    window->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

I read up on why this might be occurring and saw that it was something about needing to have the class defined in a header file. How would I go about doing that correctly given this code?

Comment: Did you provide a function body for your destructor somewhere?

Comment: Add header to .pro and run qmake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments: The missing function body for ~myMainWindow() was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from missing the destructor definition, you are also missing the `Q_OBJECT` macro, which is mandatory for all `QObject` derived classes. If you had that, you'd get another error about the MOC generated files, when you define `QObject` derived classes in `main.cpp` you need to include the MOC file manually. This is not the case if you use a dedicated h and cpp file for `QObject` derived classes.

Comment: Thank you. I just wanted to get this example working so that I know it can be done. I'm going to be modifying it to comply with the things you noted in your comments/answer.